# How to upgrade a specfic python library when I have multiple python installations at different locations?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I am using OSX, on which I have multiple python installations at different locations on my file system. I want to upgrade my matplotlib library, which is currently at version 2.1.1, while the latest version is 2.2.2. I tried to use `pip install --upgrade matplotlib`, but it gives a message (here I show only the first line)

`Requirement already up-to-date: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (2.2.2)`

However, I actually intended to upgrade the outdated matplotlib package in

`/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use the full path to `pip` to install in your different installations (e.g. `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip` but I would really look into virtual environments to manage your packages.

Comment: does osx support "which python"? In general, each separate install has to have its own environment, usually a virtual env. If you use pip in that environment, it should effect that installation.

Comment: @KennyOstrom, yes `which -a python` will show all installs of python in your `PATH`.

Comment: Why would you have more than one on the path? What's the value of PYTHONPATH? Normally you have to change the environment so everything points to one python installation (usually by means of a venv).

Answer (score 0):

Using the full pip path should work:

`/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip install --upgrade matplotlib`

However, I suggest looking into [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) for managing multiple Python installations + their packages, or at least [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) for managing just the packages.